# Dúvida monitorando o TomCat com Java VisualVM

Tags: java

Dentro da minha pasta Bin do jdk eu acessei o “jvisualvm.exe”, ele não está nas variáveis de ambiente da máquina, mais após isso eu configurei o tomcat 8:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Reiniciei o serviço e dentro o VisualVM eu tentei acessar mais estou com o erro da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já existe algo a ocupar a ligação, provavelmente não foi encerrada a ligação anterior, tenta encontrar e fechar a outra instância do visualVM mas pode ser preciso um reboot para limpar ligações.

Comment: O Tomcat e o jvisualvm estão na mesma máquina? então não precisa configurar esses parâmetros no tomcat. Quando abrir o visualvm, as aplicações java que estão rodando serão listadas.